# work area sharing in website. is possible?

Tags: flash, screen

Please see the video in this site http://www.tinyeye.com/Online-Speech-Therapy-For-Parents/How-Online-Speech-Therapy-Can-Benefit-Your-Child.php

It is actually a teacher teaching to a student, via video chatting.

One player playing the game and another one can see the playing game in the web page(not in the web cam).

My question is, any possibilities to view the same screen by two members?

Answer (score 0):

Use a free software called **Teamviewer**.
Install it at both ends and learn how to use from documentation provided on companys site..

[Website Link](http://www.teamviewer.com/hi/index.aspx)